Can't manage to make Vercel environmental variables work with Next.js app
In my simple weather application I have several components where I fetch data from an external API. While working on localhost I had no problems.
My .env.local is like this:
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY=my-key

And I'm accessing this environment using process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY in my code.
Then I deployed it on Vercel and created an environmental variable called API_KEY and used it. I wrote process.env.API_KEY everywhere where it is needed.
I have tried to follow a few suggestions that I have found on the internet, but nothing seemed to fix it for me. Keep getting undefined instead of the key.
Would it make a difference if I fetch data in several components, some of which were client components?
I have tried using different variable names, including process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY to access variable from Vercel. The last one worked, but of course the api key is visible to everyone.

You have the right idea - your env variables must be the same in the code and in the .env file. If you call it NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY in your .env.local file, you have to call it as process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_KEY in your code as  well. This will be for both development AND production environments.
The thing you want to be careful about here is exposing your API key publicly. If you can't define your API key without the NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix, it likely means you're passing your API key to the client which is a security vulnerability (since malicious actors can find the key in the source code and use it themselves).
To prevent this, make sure you're only doing API calls with your API key on the server side, either in a server component, route handler, or a server action (assuming you're using Next.js 13/14).
So, to summarize, make sure your environment variables are named the same everywhere, and make sure you don't expose your API keys to the client.
Name your env variable API_KEY, call it with process.env.API_KEY, and if that breaks your code, move it to the server to prevent security vulnerabilities.
I hope this helps!

So what I have tried is to create an environment variable API_KEY on Vercel, and then in my code I was accessing my key by using process.env.API_KEY. When I deployed the app, it could not access that environment variable from Vercel. My thought was that the app is looking in local code rather then Vercel, but I was not able to confirm this or find a way to fix it, in case that was the case.

Can you confirm that you’re accessing the variable on the server side? If you try accessing a non-public environment variable on the client it’ll be undefined.
